# multiple lists or one multidimensional list for calculations

Tags: python, arrays, physics

Say I have some calculations for physics. I was wondering what the best practice is for initializing arrays to store, for instance, position and velocity data, to which I append values in loops. My question is, should I initialize individual lists/numpy array for each of the information (position, velocity, acceleration) or should I initialize one multidimensional list/numpy array or pandas dataframe to store these data and label the columns.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

position = []
velocity = []
acceleration = []

for t in np.arange(0, 100):
    #some calculations which append position, velocity,
    #and acceleration data for each small step t to the above lists.
```

**OR**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

position = []
velocity = []
acceleration = []

data = np.array([position, velocity, acceleration])

for t in np.arange(0, 100):
    #some calculations which append position, velocity,
    #and acceleration data for each small step t to the individual arrays in the above multidimensional array.
```

Any advice on the best practice of this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use the approach that returns correct results and you think will make most sense to you when you return to it in six months

Comment: @MadPhysicist makes sense

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is that you are not allocating space for new numpy arrays on every iteration, since this could result in very poor performance.

If you're using your option #2 then note that the size of your array at the start is (3, 0), allowing space for zero elements. A new array would need to be created with enough space to hold your first results. This would repeat on every iteration, becoming more and more costly as the array grows. I recommend one of the two following solutions:

Either:

Preallocate a numpy array with all the space it will need, and fill it one row at a time

```
data = np.empty(N, 3)

for row_idx in range(N):
    data[row_idx, 0] =  # position calc.
    data[row_idx, 1] =  # velocity calc.
    data[row_idx, 2] =  # acceleration calc.
```

Or:

Store a series of values in 3 lists and then construct numpy arrays from them after the loop. These can then be concatenated if desired.

Perhaps the first is better.